# Using variables in XmlSlurper's GPath

Tags: xml, groovy

Is there a way to have XmlSlurper get arbitrary elements through a variable?
e.g. so I can do something like
input file:

```
<file>
    <record name="some record" />
    <record name="some other record" />
</file>

def xml = new XmlSlurper().parse(inputFile)
String foo = "record"
return xml.{foo}.size()
```

I've tried using {} and ${} and () how do I escape variables like that?  Or isn't there a way?
and is it possible to use results from closures as the arguments as well?  So I could do something like

```
String foo = file.record
int numRecords = xml.{foo.find(/.\w+$/)}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
import groovy.xml.*

def xmltxt = """<file>
    <record name="some record" />
    <record name="some other record" />
</file>"""

def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmltxt)
String foo = "record"
return xml."${foo}".size()
```

Comment: This doesn't work for elements not immediate children of the root. Observe:
def xmltxt = """
<file>
  <something>
    <record name="some record" />
    <record name="some other record" />
  </something>
</file>
"""

def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmltxt)
String foo = "something.record"
return xml."${foo}".size()

Any other suggestions?

Comment: I don't know of any good way, you could split the string:  def aNode = xml
foo.split("\\.").each {
    aNode = aNode."${it}"
}
return aNode.size()

Comment: +1. Thank you, the comment helped me, too. But please, put it into the answer body, as is, it is almost unreadable

Comment: It isn't exactly true that it has to be at the root, more that you can only do one part, not specify multiple parts in a single variable: def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmltxt)
String part1 = "something"
String part2 = "record"
println(xml."${part1}"."${part2}".size())

Comment: @JohnWagenleitner nice workaround for `node.another` paths in your comment, IMO I think that you must add it to your answer +1 `:)`

Comment: @JohnWagenleitner, @KeeganIt didn't work to set values `xml."${foo}"= value` . @Frank I think this case is to assign `partX` dinamically. Any other clue?

Answer (score 6):

This answer offers a code example, and owes a lot to John W's comment in his answer.

Consider this:

```
import groovy.util.* 

def xml = """<root>
  <element1>foo</element1>
  <element2>bar</element2>
  <items>
     <item>
       <name>a</name>
       <desc>b</desc>
     </item>
     <item>
        <name>c</name>
        <desc>x</desc>
     </item>
  </items>
</root>"""

def getNodes = { doc, path ->
    def nodes = doc
    path.split("\\.").each { nodes = nodes."${it}" }
    return nodes
}

def resource = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
def xpaths = ['/root/element1','/root/items/item/name']

xpaths.each { xpath ->
    def trimXPath = xpath.replace("/root/", "").replace("/",".")
    println "xpath = ${trimXPath}"
    getNodes(resource, trimXPath).each { println it }
}
```

Comment: Folks, what about to assign values? I mean: `String foo = "something.record" 
xml."${foo}"= value
` which your [even @Keegan and,  @John.W] advisement doesn't work :(, any clue?

Comment: Folks, I found the solution, I used `def node= getNodes(..)    node.replaceBody   value`   ..  I see that I'm a trainee in XMLSlurper :(  .

Answer (score 0):

Based on Michael's solution, this provides support for indexes, like `'/root/element1[1]'`

```
def getNodes = { doc, path ->
    def nodes = doc
    path.split("\\.").each {
      if (it.endsWith(']'))
      {
        def name_index = it.tokenize('[]') // "attributes[1]" => ["attributes", "1"]
        nodes = nodes."${name_index[0]}"[name_index[1].toInteger()]
      }
      else nodes = nodes."${it}"
    }
    return nodes
}
```