# Groovy replace node values in xml with xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, groovy

I want to replace the node values in a xml in groovy.
I have the values in xpath in a hashmap like:

```
 def param = [:]       
 param["/Envelope/Body/GetWeather/CityName"] = "Berlin"
 param["/Envelope/Body/GetWeather/CountryName"] = "Germany"
```

XML File:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope   xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
      <web:GetWeather xmlns:web="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
          <web:CityName>Test</web:CityName>
          <web:CountryName>Test</web:CountryName>
      </web:GetWeather>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

How can I replace the node values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using [`XmlSlurper`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/XmlSlurper.html) instead probably it's an easy way. You can define your map using the node name as a key and the text as a value iterate over it changing the node in the Xml. You can use something similar the code below:

```
import groovy.util.XmlSlurper
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil

def xmlString = '''<soapenv:Envelope   xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
      <web:GetWeather xmlns:web="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
          <web:CityName>Test</web:CityName>
          <web:CountryName>Test</web:CountryName>
      </web:GetWeather>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>'''

def param = [:]       
param["CityName"] = "Berlin"
param["CountryName"] = "Germany"

// parse the xml
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmlString)

// for each key,value in the map
param.each { key,value ->
    // change the node value if the its name matches
    xml.'**'.findAll { if(it.name() == key) it.replaceBody value }
}

println XmlUtil.serialize(xml)
```

**Another possible solution**

Instead if you want to use the complete path not only the node name to change its value (to be more robust) you can define you `XPath` using `.` notation instead of `/` notation and avoid root node name (in your case `Envelope`) because in the parsed xml object it's already there. So changing your XPath you can have something like:

```
def param = [:]       
// since envelope is the root node it's not necessary
param["Body.GetWeather.CityName"] = "Berlin"
param["Body.GetWeather.CountryName"] = "Germany"
```

All together in the code:

```
import groovy.util.XmlSlurper
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil

def xmlString = '''<soapenv:Envelope   xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
      <web:GetWeather xmlns:web="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
          <web:CityName>Test</web:CityName>
          <web:CountryName>Test</web:CountryName>
      </web:GetWeather>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>'''

def param = [:]       
// since envelope is the root node it's not necessary
param["Body.GetWeather.CityName"] = "Berlin"
param["Body.GetWeather.CountryName"] = "Germany"

def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmlString)

param.each { key,value ->
    def node = xml
    key.split("\\.").each {
      node = node."${it}"
    }
    node.replaceBody value
}

println XmlUtil.serialize(xml)
```

Note that in the second solution I use this snippet:

```
    def node = xml
    key.split("\\.").each {
      node = node."${it}"
    }
```

This snippet it's from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1308834/1218618) and [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307919/using-variables-in-xmlslurpers-gpath#comment1256192_1308834) which is a workaround to solve `.` path based using variables (a good workaround IMO `:)`)

Hope this helps,

Comment: Hi, this helps for this example, but I need something  more generic. For example when the xml looks like <Person><firstname></firstname></Person><Customer><firstname></firstname></Customer> how should I deal with this? Thats way i wanted to use xpath

Comment: @Peter You can use the second approach in the answer, with the second approach you can add the `path` to your elements in your map.

Comment: Hi, I have to try your another solution, just tried the first one

Comment: @Peter nice, hope it helps `:)`