# Using variables as GPath expression in XmlSlurper

Tags: xml, groovy, xmlslurper

Given the following XML document:

```
<root>
  <Person>
    <Name>JOHN DOE</Name>
  </Person>
</root>
```

With a Groovy script I parse the document like this:

```
def xmlFile = new File("mydocument.xml")
def root = new XmlSlurper().parse(xmlFile)
println(root.Person.Name)
```

Is it possible to make the GPath expression variable so that it would like something like this?

```
def xmlFile = new File("mydocument.xml")
def root = new XmlSlurper().parse(xmlFile)
def gpathExpr = "root.Person.Name"
println(gpathExpr) // <-- Evaluate this during runtime
```

Comment: I also saw that post and referenced it but there is another solution that uses `Eval` to actually evaluate the GPath expression.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two working solutions (in the form of JUnit Groovy tests). The former was derived from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12872979/70465); the latter I experimented with and found on my own. I think the latter is more closely aligned with what you were looking for, but the former is probably more robust.

**Side note**: I don't know how you intend to read in the "variable path" expression, but you should be **very careful** to sanitize it completely because you do **not** want to run `Eval.me()` on arbitrary, unsanitized, user-provided input.

```
@Test
void testShouldUseVariableGPathExpression() {
    // Arrange
    def xmlContent = """<root>
  <Person>
    <Name>JOHN DOE</Name>
  </Person>
</root>"""

    def getNodes = { doc, path ->
        def nodes = doc
        path.split("\\.").each { nodes = nodes."${it}" }
        return nodes
    }

    def root = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmlContent)

    // Don't reference 'root' here
    def path = "Person.Name"

    // Act
    def personName = getNodes(root, path)
    logger.info("Parsed ${path}: ${personName}")

    // Assert
    assert personName == "JOHN DOE"
}

@Test
void testShouldUseVariableGPathExpressionAndEval() {
    // Arrange
    def xmlContent = """<root>
  <Person>
    <Name>JOHN DOE</Name>
  </Person>
</root>"""

    def root = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmlContent)
    def path = "root.Person.Name"
    def expression = "evaluatedPath = ${path}"
    logger.info("Generated expression: ${expression}")

    // Act
    def evaluatedPath = Eval.me('root', root, path)
    logger.info("Evaluated result: ${evaluatedPath}")

    def personName = evaluatedPath
    logger.info("Parsed ${path}: ${personName}")

    // Assert
    assert personName == "JOHN DOE"
}
```